# How to connect blue tooth connection in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, nuget-package

I want to connect windows phone through blue tooth. Iphone have this facility. If wp8 hav this feature,what is the process. Is there any Nuget Package for this in Visual Studio? Any website links or tutorials are accepted.

Comment: WP8 has Bluetooth and an API - what would you like to use it for?

Comment: want to connect it to heart meter.

Answer (score 1):

Both the official MSDN documentation and Nokia Developer Wiki have a good overview of what's possible using Bluetooth on Windows Phone 8...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Introduction_to_Bluetooth_support_on_Windows_Phone_8

As well as a link to a sample Bluetooth project which should get you started...

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-device-644870ba